# Silverlight merged resource dictionary outside xap

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

How can I have my merged resource dictionary live outside of the xap file in plain text so my clients can edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following links:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=371
http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/lee_roth/archive/2009/05/20/load-xaml-resource-dictionaries-at-runtime.aspx
Also, See accepted answer on this one: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/109906/250188.aspx